# How to test Python modules marked as executable from the command line

Tags: python, testing

I have a collection of Python bin files which does some processing based on logic and it worries me that changes might caused unexpected errors to show up. Would it be too much of a stretch to create unit tests for these bin files or what kinds of tests would be the best for them ?

To clarify I wrote my own Python files which acts as bin files (executables) which does things like process logics then run multiprocessing threads, daemonizing functions, consuming mq calls etc.

I have a big python file which is used as a bin file like this:

```
<function defs here>
def main():

    global mq, queue, edge_mq, txn_time

    queue = Queue()

    # Clean up stale configs
    cleanup_all_stale_config()

    my_mq = MyMQconnection()
    my_mq.daemon  = True
    my_mq.start()

    mq = CoreMQconnection()
    mq.daemon = True
    mq.start()
    txn_time = time()
    orm.begin()
    sync_configs()
    orm.commit()

    mq.consume("workers", receive_message, no_ack=False, prefetch_count=200)
    my_mq.consume("workers", receive_message, no_ack=False, prefetch_count=200)
    config_thread = Thread(target=update_config)
    config_thread.daemon = True
    config_thread.start()

    while config_thread.is_alive() and mq.is_alive() and edge_mq.is_alive():
        sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What is the best way to test a script like this ?

Comment: bin files?  Python programs are usually text, or have you been using `py2exe`?  If you don't want them changed then remove write access from them.  Of course you should have tests, exactly which tests depends on functionality.

Comment: I suppose you mean `.pyo` files? If you've structured your code well you could use `pyunit` to add unit tests. If you've not structured your code well you might want to start adding tests that uses the code in a realistic use case (before restructuring your code to allow for unit tests).

Comment: `bin` meaning binary? Or just `.py` files with `+x`?

Comment: .py files with +x bit set